# Variables de entorno java

Tags: java, variables, variables-globales

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]introducir la descripción de la imagen aquíintroducir la descripción de la imagen aquí[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Perdonar si la pregunta es muy elemental. 
Tenía la version 6 de java instalada en mi pc. Al intentar arrancar eclipse Oxygen no funcionaba con dicha version por lo que he instalado la version 8 de java. Sin cambiar las variables de entorno de windows (JAVA_HOME, etc) he ejecutado desde la linea de comandos un java -version y la respuesta ha sido java 8 y el eclipse ha arrancado. Sin embargo las variables de entorno siguen apuntando a java 6. No se si tiene que ver con que las variables sean del Sistema o del Usuario pq he visto diferentes path. Podéis aconsejarme documentación donde aclarar mis dudas. 
Muchas gracias

Comment: Por aclarar un poco más no he desinstalado ninguna versión ambas conviven.

Comment: Qué sistema operativo tienes?

Comment: Windows 10......

Comment: He añadido una imagen con los valores de la varible de sistema path, en la primera fila (linea que creo que se ha añadido al instalar java 8) hay una ruta a un java (que creo es version 8) en la ultima esta la que puse yo manualmente cuando instale java 6

Comment: Se usa la primera ruta en la que encuentre el programa en tu caso sería la que está en la primera línea, la que te agregó el instalador de oracle, si subes la utlima antes de la de oracle te tomaría la jdk 6. Saludos

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias zerocool.

Comment: zerocool te voy a preguntar una ultima cosa

Comment: si la variable del sistema apunta a una version de java y la de usuario a otra supongo que tendrá prioridad la del sistema y luego de arriba a abajo no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que eclipse use una instalación específica de java, la misma se puede configurar en el archivo `eclipse.ini`:

Hay que agregar el argumento vm y el path al `bin\javaw.exe` de la instalación de java:

*Ejemplo:*

```
-vm
C:\mi\instalacion\java8\bin\javaw.exe
```

**Importante:**
1) El path está en la línea siguiente al argumento (`-vm`)
2) Este argumento tiene que estar antes (más arriba) del argumento `-vmargs`
3) El path no debe tener espacios, si fuera el caso, usar el nombre del directorio mostrado en un "`dir`" de `cmd` (que contiene el caracter `~`)

**Aclaración**: Esta es la JVM que usará eclipse para ejecutarse, es independiente de la JVM o JDK que luego se configure para los proyectos.

Ref: [Eclipse.ini](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)

> Si yo actualmente ejecuto en mi pc cualquier programa que requiera la
>   jvm cual usaría, ya que según la linea de comandos (java -version)
>   esta usaría java 8 sin embargo en las variables de entorno de windows
>   se apunta a java 6

Si ejecutas `java` desde la linea de comando, tomará la primera ocurrencia de tu variable de entorno `PATH`

De otro modo, fijate en el panel de control Java (en control panel de windows), ahi está la versión que el sistema utilizará por default. Esos valores si no me equivoco se guardan en la registry.

JAVA_HOME es una variable de entorno para guardar la raíz del directorio java que querés usar, pero depende de la aplicación usar esa variable o no.

Un uso que le podes dar, por ejemplo, es setear el JAVA_HOME, y setear el PATH en base al JAVA_HOME. De esa forma al cambiar el JAVA_HOME, indirectamente cambias la versión de java que se ejecuta de línea de comando.

Comment: Gracias Juan, muy interesante. Pero sigo con algunas dudas. Si yo actualmente ejecuto en mi pc cualquier programa que requiera la jvm cual usaría, ya que según la linea de comandos (java -version) esta usaría java 8 sin embargo en las variables de entorno de windows se apunta a java 6

Comment: Agrego acá la respuesta a la útima pregunta @Alex, las variables de usuario son evaluadas antes que las de sistema, piensa que podemos tener una consiguración específica para un usuario por ende ésta debe tener una relevancia mayor, si el usuario no tiene una configuración específica para el, entonces vamos a las variables generales o de sistema. Te dejo un link donde lo comentan: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/system-user-environment-variables-windows, recuerda marca la respuesta, ésta me parece acorde. Saludos!

Comment: Ok, gracias por la informacion Juan.

Comment: Hola, Juan perdona las molestias. Pero en otro pc tengo dos java una establecida en las variables de Sistema y otra en las de Usuario. Pero cuando ejecuto java -version me devuelve la del sistema.

Comment: Agrego al comienzo la captura de pantalla de la variable de usuario java 7 (entiendo que la de sistema este bien porque me devuelve java 8)

Comment: En una ventana cmd ejecuta el comando: echo %PATH% fijate ahí cuál es el la primera instalación de java que aparece. (Si en lugar de %PATH% pones %<OTRA VARIABLE>% podrás ver el contenido efectivo que tiene para el usuario ejecutando el cmd).

Comment: Por otro lado y referido al comentario sobre la evaluación de las variables de entorno, PATH es la excepción a la regla. La variable de usuario se agrega a la variable de sistema. Esto hace que la configuración del sistema sea considerada primero que cualquier agregado que haya hecho un usuario.

Comment: Si no te he entendido mal, entonces mis aplicaciones de eclipse tal cual esta configurado actualmente se están ejecutando con java 8??

Comment: Quiero decir mis proyectos

Comment: Hola, en un proyecto pequeño que tengo he añadido      String version=System.getProperty("java.version");
System.out.println(version);

Comment: Perdon por el desorden, añadi esas dos líneas de codigo y por la consola de eclipse me mostró (1.6.0).  Cuando he comentado lo del segundo pc (7y8) omiti que tenia una 6 tb instalada porque no le dí importancia. Otro dato es que esta pequeño proyecto es un proyecto web que le he alojado en un Websphere